# Adding two class names using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
    document.Deceasedinfo.DOBOfPrimary.className = "deceasedinfoinput datepick3";
```

how to add two different class for a object in a table. i tried this one. one class is getting applied but other in is not getting applied.

how to solve this.

Comment: the object has already a class defined? which class is not applied?

Comment: no i haven't defined it.

Comment: so double check your css class names and be sure that the class applied is not overriding the rules defined on the other class

Comment: What you are doing should work - I suggest debugging in Firefox/Firebug and seeing what is actually happening.

Comment: this two class names are different class files. and not over riding. $('.datepick3').datepick({'dateFormat':'mm/dd/yyyy', 'alignment':'top'}); this is how i defined the second class. it is not getting applied

Comment: The jQuery (I assume it's jQuery) code you show in that last comment doesn't define a class, it selects elements that already have the `datepick3` class and applies the `.datepick()` method to them - this won't apply to other elements that have the `datepick3` class added to them later. Also, if you're using jQuery, why not use the `.addClass()` method?

Comment: how to use jquery add class for the above method?? could please give an example?? @nnnnnn

Comment: There are examples on the [`addClass()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/). You're not trying to use jQuery without using the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) are you?

Answer (score 0):

If the element has no class, give it one. Otherwise, append a space followed by the new className:

```
var el = document.getElementById('hello');
if(el) {
  el.className += el.className ? ' someClass' : 'someClass';
}
```